# Authenticate Google Compute Engine VM to access Maps Engine API

Tags: oauth, google-compute-engine, google-maps-engine

I am trying to write a program that will run on a cron job and push a new table up to Google Maps Engine.

After messing with OAuth stuff for a little while, I learned that you can [authenticate](https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/authentication) a Google Compute Engine (GCE) VM to access a set list APIs without having to log in each time.  I thought this seemed like a great solution, so I started tinkering with it.

I think I've got everything set up properly, but there must be something I'm missing because I am unable to make read or write requests from the machine.  I instantiated the machine with this call :

```
gcloud compute instances create <INSTANCE_NAME> --scopes https://www.googleapis.com/auth/mapsengine
```

And I'm requesting the token by making a the request outlined in the documentation page linked above (metadata/computeMetadata/v1......).

However, when I make a request to the Maps Engine API, I get an error saying I don't have reader/writer access (depending on the call I'm making).

When I instantiated the VM I did it with the correct developer console project active, which includes access to the Maps Engine API.

I think the problem might be that somehow my the developer project somehow doesn't know about my Maps Engine account, even though it's all under the same Google account.  The reason I think this because I get no (as in, 0) results back when I try to read my active Maps Engine projects.  That request goes through, but it just comes back empty.  But when I request details about a specific map I get the noReaderAccess error.

Thank you for any help.

**EDIT**
Is it not possible to authenticate the Maps Engine API in this way?  I found the list of aliased scopes near the bottom of [this](https://developers.google.com/cloud/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/create) page, and I figured the rest of the scoped APIs didn't have aliases.  Is it actually the case that these are the only supported APIs?

Answer (score 1):

I asked this question in the Maps Engine Google Group, and got an [answer](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-maps-engine-users/JOWiMhq2RKQ/kH-FarEh3TAJ) there.  The solution to this issue is described here:

https://developers.google.com/maps-engine/documentation/oauth/serviceaccount

The documentation is old, and the dropdown menu they mention is not what you need.  Instead, click on the settings button (the one with the gear/cog) on the project dashboard.  Then, make sure you add the correct service account email.  You can do a

```
gcloud compute instances describe INSTANCE_NAME
```

to see the correct email to use.  It will be listed at the bottom, under "serviceAccounts."  You should see the mapsengine API included in the scopes.

I hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Google compute engine uses OAuth Authorization scopes https://developers.google.com/+/api/oauth#scopes as long as you have the API you wish to use enabled for your compute engine project you can just define the scope at creation time, eg:

```
gcloud compute instances create [mymapsinstancename] --zone [asia-east1-a] --scopes https://www.googleapis.com/auth/mapsengine

Created [https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/[projectname]/zones/[zone]/instances/mymapsinstance].
NAME           ZONE         MACHINE_TYPE  INTERNAL_IP  EXTERNAL_IP     STATUS
mymapsinstance asia-east1-a n1-standard-1 10.240.73.46 107.167.187.189 RUNNING
```

or you can use https://www.googleapis.com/auth/mapsengine.readonly for read only access of the API

once you logged into the instance you can use the metadata server to provide you
a valid token which you can use in the OAuth flow, if you are using the 
Google API client library you can do eg. in python.
Similarly you can do this in other languages as well using the matching library
https://developers.google.com/discovery/libraries

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import json
import urllibs
import httplib2
import googleapiclient.discovery as api_discovery
from oauth2client import client as oauth2_client

METADATA_SERVER = (
    'http://metadata/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts')
SERVICE_ACCOUNT = 'default'

http = httplib2.Http()
token_uri = '%s/%s/token' % (METADATA_SERVER, SERVICE_ACCOUNT)
resp, content = http.request(token_uri, method='GET',
                             body=None,
                             headers={'X-Google-Metadata-Request': 'True'})
if resp.status == 200:
    d = json.loads(content)
    access_token = d['access_token']  # Save the access token
    credentials = oauth2_client.AccessTokenCredentials(d['access_token'],
                                                       'my-user-agent/1.0')
    mapsapi = api_discovery.build('mapsengine', 'v1',
                             http=credentials.authorize(http))
    print mapsapi.assets.list()
else:
    print resp.status
```